# Deploying App to Portal for ArcGIS (ArcGIS Enterprise) from ArcGIS Experience Builder Developer Edition

Tags: arcgis-portal, arcgis-enterprise, arcgis-experience-builder

I am new to ArcGIS Experience Builder Developer Edition but managed to create an experience with some theme customizations.

The next step would be now to deploy it to my Portal to make it accessible to my users.

I am trying to follow these instructions here: https://developers.arcgis.com/experience-builder/guide/deployment-topics/

However, it seems I am too much a beginner to get it work.

Is there any more detailed explanation available?

I am already lost on step one:

> Unzip the downloaded experience and copy the folder to your web
> server.

Where exactly should I copy the folder to?

I assume the web server is the server where Portal for ArcGIS installed but into which folder?

Also, are there more specific information on how to add and register the app?

The links provided refer to ArcGIS Online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Developer edition, you still need a Portal (or Online) as a mechanism for Experience Builder to get maps and data from. So, when you do the initial setup it asks for your Portal URL and an AppKey. This provides a coupling that allows the Builder to get the data in said Portal. That's about the extent of involvement with Portal and your Experience you've made.

You cannot upload or deploy the Experience into your Portal. You need to deploy your Experience (the web app you've made) into a full blown web server. Something like IIS, or Apache, or....well there are literally dozens of web servers you could use. If you deployed Web Adapators with your Portal, you'll have some sort of web server. Odds are, IIS if you're using Windows. You can *probably* make use of the same IIS that hosts your Web Adaptors to host your app. (But I'm not in your environment, nor your IT group, so I can't say for sure). Assuming you can leverage your IIS, deployment is as "simple as":

- Navigate to the IIS folder, typically at `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`
- Make a new directory for your app, call it 'myapp' for example
- Extract the contents of the zip file you've generated into that directory

Done. See your app at **http://your_Server_name/myapp** If your IIS is the same one for your Enterprise Web Adaptors, then the URL is the same you use to access your Portal. Just  with the `/myapp` endpoint.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly the piece of information that I was missing. We work with IIS and it worked.